# Extracting combinations from a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
List = [1, 2, 3]
```

...and I want to print out all possible combinations such that the output is like:

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1, 2, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

So far my code is this:

```
E=[]
i=0
for seq in L[i:]:
    E.append(seq)
    i += 1
    print(E)
```

Which gives my first 3 outputs. Is there a way for me to loop it so that the index goes up by 1 so I can get my desired output?

Edit; so I basically want to write a code which summarizes this:

```
List = [1, 2, 3]
E = []
F = []
G = []


for seq in List[0:]:
    E.append(seq)
    print(E)

for seq in List[1:]:
    F.append(seq)
    print(F)

for seq in List[2:]:
    G.append(seq)
    print(G)
```

I pretty much want to know if I can loop the index so that I don't have to create multiple for loops and maybe apply it to a longer list.

Comment: what about [1,3]?

Comment: Look at the stdlib itertools.

Comment: You are creating combinations, so use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). The combinations are of length 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: use 2 loops... 1 for iterating the indexes and other for making combinations

Comment: Are you looking for combinations or sliding windows of different length? For eg, is `[1,3]` a possible output?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating combinations of increasing length, so use `itertools.combinations()` with a length ranging from 1 to `len(inputlist)`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> List = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(List)):
...     for combo in combinations(List, r=i + 1):
...         print(combo)
...
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

`combinations()` produces tuples, but those are trivially converted to lists if you must have a mutable sequence for each.